# GIOChannel won't detect G_IO_IN

Tags: linux, sockets, glib, gio

I use blocking IO (because this seems the easiest way to write larger amounts of data to a socket).

I would like to detect if there is any data to read, so I use `g_io_channel_get_buffer_condition()`. The problem is that it will always give back `4`, and the  bit `1` for `G_IO_IN` is never set.

The sending and receiving works fine in all other aspects. The object is created from a Unix socket. Is there any other aspect I need to set up for this function to correctly signal that there are bytes available to read?